# Most efficient way to develop using WAR files?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, war, spring-tool-suite

So I'm really new to the Java webstack world, and had a question on the most efficient solution to my problem.  Some background information first; I'm running Tomcat on a Lubuntu 14.04 server listening on Port 80, developing on a separate Windows computer in Spring Tool Suite (developing Spring applications obviously).  Currently, whenever I want to test something, I...

1) Export the project as a WAR file from Spring Tool Suite
2) Undeploy the old WAR file from the server from the Tomcat manager webapp
3) Deploy the new WAR file that I just got from Spring Tool Suite (which takes ~15 seconds)

Is there any faster way to do this?  Normally, I wouldn't be opposed to just developing on localhost.  However, I'm going to be doing a group project, so we would all need access to the same SQL server, which would be the one hosted on the Lubuntu 14.04 server.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Use maven; add an embedded Tomcat configuration - you can deploy the app in a few seconds. Or run your Tomcat server with a debugger, submit code changes instantaneously from the IDE. Or use a framework like Spring Boot to embed a web server into the application. Your choice. P.S. access the SQL server remotely.

Comment: You can connect from a local tomcat to the remote sql server, ideally every developer would have its own environment (tomcat, sql sever etc.) so that when developing you aren't interfering with each other. Frameworks like Spring Boot or Dropwizard can help with setting things up as they use an embedded tomcat and still have the option to be deployed (if that would be still needed). For deployment to servers you want to have some process in place, preferably you are deploying artifacts from your build server or as part of the build proces on that server.

Answer (score 0):

Most IDEs have the ability to deploy to server for both development and production purposes.
Those that don't have this ability inbuilt, ususally have a add-on that enables this.

You can also use build tools such as maven or gradle to undertake these actions.

Since you raised a good point of working with others it is important that all are across the deployment process and that the process is standardised to ensure no weird issues/bugs pop up.